# how to delete account (multiple select) in firebase users tab?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to delete multiple user accounts, I want to multi-select user accounts, I have many users, is there any way to do that?!

Comment: Using the console? Using code? Please provide more information.

Comment: no problem, using the console, or using code, just tell me how, it would be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a feature request for the Firebase console. Please file that with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) - there's nothing we, community volunteers, can do to help you improve the experience in the console.

If you don't want to delete users manually, you can always write code using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to [list all users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) and [delete them individually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user).

Comment: I don't know much about firebase admin ask, I have used firebase CLI I don't know if you mean that

Comment: Then follow the provided links to learn more.

Comment: *firebaser here* @TheCodeWhisperer The Firebase CLI doesn't have any commands to delete users. If you want to efficiently delete multiple users, the Admin SDKs are currently the only way - and filing a feature request to allow that in the Firebase web console too sounds like good plan either way.

Comment: Thanks Engineer @FrankvanPuffelen, really appreciated your explanation brother.

Comment: Hello, my application is flutter, but these links that you sent to me seems like it's just for nodejs, java, python, GO, C#

Comment: Right, the Admin SDK doesn't run inside an app.  It's runs on backend servers or programs you run on your own computer using only the languages you see supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it through Javascript, here's a code snippet you can run. It will delete the users one by one starting from the most top. You would need to define the total users you would like to delete.

```js
const remove = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document
        .querySelector("edit-account-menu .mat-mdc-button-touch-target")
        .click();

      setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelectorAll(".mat-mdc-menu-item-text")[2].click();

        setTimeout(() => {
          document
            .querySelector(".confirm-button .mat-mdc-button-touch-target")
            .click();

          resolve();
        }, 1000);
      }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
  });
};

async function main() {
  const totalItems = 3;
  const itemList = Array.from(Array(totalItems).keys());

  for await (const item of itemList) {
    await remove();
    console.log(`removed ${item}`);
  }
}

main();
```